# Email is not being fetched from facebook sdk 4.7.0 in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I want to fetch the first name, last name and email from the facebook login and pass them to the web service. But the problem is I am getting the first name and last name but email.
I have been searching for this for the last two  days but could not find it. Below is my code:

```
      @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager=CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    loginButton=(LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.fbLogin);
    // loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewInflation();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
        requestQueue = volleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
        fbRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

        loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_birthday");
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                System.out.println(profile.getFirstName());
                System.out.println(profile.getId());
                System.out.println(loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId());

        System.out.println("Auth Token: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {
                                if (response.getError() != null) {
                                    // handle error
                                } else {
                                    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                                    System.out.println(profile.getFirstName());
                                    System.out.println(profile.getId());
                                    String email = object.optString("email");
                                    System.out.println("Email is "+email);
                                    String fname = object.optString("fname");
                                    String lname = object.optString("lname");
                                    Log.i("Email", email);
                                    Log.i("fname", fname);
                                    Log.i("lname", lname);
                                    //     Log.d("Response", response.getInnerJsobject.toString());

                                }
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.getString("fields", "id,first_name,last_name,user_birthday,email");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // info.setText("Login Attempt Cancelled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                //  info.setText("Login Attempt Failed");
            }
        });
    }}
```

Comment: Code seems perfect..I think prob is there in developer page.Have you added your mail in developer site ?

Comment: Does the user have an email address that is verified?

Comment: Does email returning null ?

Comment: its returning me first_name,last_name,app_id but not email

Answer (score 0):

Try using another facebook account or that have valid verified email.
According to facebook sdk [Developers Reference Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/) they mentioned:

> The person's primary email address listed on their profile. This field will not be returned if no valid email address is available

So be sure to check that.